# How to throw an error message when there is no method mapping in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-validation

How to throw an error message when there is no method mapping in Spring controller.
In the following example GET /api/v1/foos doesn't exist, is there a way to throw a generic message (say api/v1/foos doesn't exist) instead of the default message.

```
{{base_url}}/fa/api/v1/foos/
{
    "message": "No static resource api/v1/foos.",
    "status": 500,
    "timestamp": "2024-02-29T12:58:50.813294104"
}
```

Comment: Based on this question, you cant use ExceptionResolver to catch errors when there is no method mapping, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804326/16034206 but the answer below it that was not accepted does provide a hack. This [link](https://bootcamptoprod.com/spring-boot-no-explicit-mapping-error-handling/#:~:text=is%20correctly%20mapped.-,Solution%2D2%3A%20Handling%20Unmapped%20Requests,-Effectively%20handling%20unmapped) should also prove informative

Answer (score 0):

You could define global elements in an ExceptionController or whatever you want to call it:

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class GlobalExceptionHandler 
{

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMethodNotSupportedException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("The requested method does not exist.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
        @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchMethodException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoSuchMethodException(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("The requested method does not exist.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

You can use custom classes, send parameters into those or simply use strings (as a parameter) for the message you want to send through these default exception classes.